# Matplotlib: Plot the result of an SQL query

Tags: python, sql, matplotlib, plot

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import _mssql
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://**:****@127.0.0.1:1433/AffectV_Test')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute('SELECT Campaign_id, SUM(Count) AS Total_Count FROM Impressions GROUP BY Campaign_id')
for row in result:
   print row

connection.close()
```

The above code generates an array:

```
(54ca686d0189607081dbda85', 4174469)
(551c21150189601fb08b6b64', 182)
(552391ee0189601fb08b6b73', 237304)
(5469f3ec0189606b1b25bcc0', 4231)
(54e35ea90189603f6b557571', 1362847)
(54f05c140189600828ee23f9', 570635)
```

How do I plot this result as a Bar Graph using matplotlib? Not sure how to plot the result of the for loop.

Comment: What are the two axes ?

Comment: @Noob The above array in the form (x,y)

Comment: x is a string as I can understand. How do you intend to plot it ?

Comment: The strings in the X axis and the corresponding numerinc value in the Y axis.

Comment: The strings are long so i assume it would look a little odd, not sure though.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention: I want it to be a simple Bar Graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take this for a starter code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import _mssql

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://**:****@127.0.0.1:1433/AffectV_Test')
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute('SELECT Campaign_id, SUM(Count) AS Total_Count FROM Impressions GROUP BY Campaign_id')


## the data

data = []
xTickMarks = []

for row in result:
   data.append(int(row[1]))
   xTickMarks.append(str(row[0]))

connection.close()


## necessary variables
ind = np.arange(len(data))                # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35                      # the width of the bars

## the bars
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, data, width,
                color='black',
                error_kw=dict(elinewidth=2,ecolor='red'))


# axes and labels
ax.set_xlim(-width,len(ind)+width)
ax.set_ylim(0,45)


ax.set_ylabel('Y LABEL')
ax.set_xlabel('X LABEL')
ax.set_title('TITLE_HERE')

ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
xtickNames = ax.set_xticklabels(xTickMarks)
plt.setp(xtickNames, rotation=45, fontsize=10)


plt.show()
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for! I will take it from here! Thank you so much.

Comment: I get this error `AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 5 or scalar` on line 31: `error_kw=dict(elinewidth=2,ecolor='red')`

Comment: Works great now. I might have to change the Steps of Y Axis. For now it is 0 to 45 which obviously doesnt make sense in this graph. I should go through the documentation :)

Comment: Try changing ax.set_ylim(0,45) to ax.set_ylim(0,max(data))

Comment: You, Sir are a Champ. Good start for me! I will continue building new stuff! Thanks again!