# Plot table values from SQL (MariaDB) with matplotlib

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib, mariadb

I would like to extract two column data and use these as values to plot a histogram on matplotlib. I have followed closely to this answer found in [Matplotlib: Plot the result of an SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979962/matplotlib-plot-the-result-of-an-sql-query) as much as I can, differing in just a few aspects (i.e. SQL module used). My script ran with an error however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_script.py", line 22, in <module>
    for row in result:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

My python script is:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb 
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='user1', password='pw', database='sensordb')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
result=cursor.execute("SELECT time, voltage FROM sensortable")

#the data

data = []
xTickMarks = []

for row in result:
    data.append(int(row[1]))
    xTickMarks.append(str(row[0]))

mariadb_connection.close()

## necessary variables
ind = np.arange(len(data))                # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35                      # the width of the bars

## the bars
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, data, width,
                color='black',
                error_kw=dict(elinewidth=2,ecolor='red'))


# axes and labels
ax.set_xlim(-width,len(ind)+width)
ax.set_ylim(0,45)


ax.set_ylabel('Voltage')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_title('Sensor measurements')

ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
xtickNames = ax.set_xticklabels(xTickMarks)
plt.setp(xtickNames, rotation=45, fontsize=10)

plt.show()
fig.savefig('plot1.jpg')
```

Updates:
I also printed the data obtained with another python script to determine the data that I was obtaining from the SQL query. Terminal prints: `Decimal('2479.00')), (u'13:15', Decimal('3182.00')), (u'13:20', Decimal('3076.00')), (u'13:25', Decimal('2795.00')), (u'13:30', Decimal('3457.00')), (u'13:35', Decimal('2515.00')), (u'13:40', Decimal('3006.00')), (u'13:45', Decimal('3618.00')), (u'13:50', Decimal('3857.00'))] (and more similar data).......)`

Given that this 'Decimal' data type might be causing the issue, how can I address it?

I have amend a line of my python script to `data.append(int(float(row[1])))` but it still returns an error `Traceback (most recent call last): File "test_select.py", line 19, in <module> data.append(int(float(row[1]))) TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Comment: It seems your *result* is `None`. Check that your query actually return records, maybe in console outside Python.

Comment: I've queried the database with `"SELECT time, voltage FROM sensortable;` in the SQL program directly, and it brings me two columns of data as expected. `152 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

Answer (score 2):

Do not assign an object to the `execute()` call but simply iterate the assigned cursor object:

```
cur = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT time, voltage FROM sensortable")

data = []
xTickMarks = []

for row in cur.fetchall():
    data.append(int(row[1]))
    xTickMarks.append(str(row[0]))
```

Comment: I got another error after making the changes: 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_script.py", line 23, in <module>
    data.append(int(row[1]))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
`

Comment: See update using `fetchall` with a change of object name to *cur* to avoid naming clashes with actual method.

Comment: Updated my code with the advised changes above. The error still reads: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_script.py", line 23, in <module>
    data.append(int(row[1]))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: I also confirmed with another test script to see if results are being drawn in from the database from a more stripped down version of this python script. Here is my terminal output: `pi@raspberrypi:~/projects $ python test_select.py
10:28, 5964.00
10:29, 6092.00
10:30, 6407.00
10:39, 2251.00
10:40, 2489.00
10:41, 8927.00
10:42, 6146.00
10:43, 8172.00
10:44, 8053.00
10:45, 7720.00
10:46, 7107.00
10:47, 6833.00
10:48, 8949.00
10:49, 8905.00
10:50, 8923.00 (and more data printed in two columns.....)`

Comment: You have MarieDB on a raspberry pi! Very interesting. What is in *test_select.py* to have data fetched like that? Use that implementation in this above script.

Comment: test_select.py has almost similar components in the SQL aspect: `#!/usr/bin/env python
import mysql.connector as mariadb

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='user1', password='pw', database='sensordb')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT time, voltage FROM sensortable")
mariadb_connection.close()

result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
 print "%s, %s" % (row[(0)], row[(1)])`

Comment: Implemented the advised changes into the test_select.py, butc still getting the same error. The terminal output reads: `10:28, 5964.00
10:29, 6092.00
10:30, 6407.00
10:39, 2251.00
10:40, 2489.00
10:41, 8927.00
10:42, 6146.00
10:43, 8172.00
10:44, 8053.00
10:45, 7720.00
10:46, 7107.00
10:47, 6833.00
10:48, 8949.00
10:49, 8905.00
10:50, 8923.00
10:57, None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_select.py", line 19, in <module>
    data.append(int(row[1]))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`.

Comment: So from these steps, it looks like the script is able to print the values drawn from the SQL database. But it seems that somehow the script runs into problems when trying to utilise this data.

Comment: I modified the script now so it reads in the last few lines `cursor.execute("SELECT time, voltage FROM sensortable")
mariadb_connection.close() result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
 print result` Terminal prints: `Decimal('2479.00')), (u'13:15', Decimal('3182.00')), (u'13:20', Decimal('3076.00')), (u'13:25', Decimal('2795.00')), (u'13:30', Decimal('3457.00')), (u'13:35', Decimal('2515.00')), (u'13:40', Decimal('3006.00')), (u'13:45', Decimal('3618.00')), (u'13:50', Decimal('3857.00'))] (and more similar data).......)`

Comment: From this terminal output, I wonder if this 'Decimal' data type might be causing the issue when the script tries to utilise the data?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12661999/1422451). Wrap in float first, then in int: `data.append(int(float(row[1])))`.

Comment: Terminal now prints: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_select.py", line 19, in <module>
    data.append(int(float(row[1])))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Comment: All very strange. What version of Python are you running? Pre 2.7?

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: Looks like your very first row does not have a *time* value (unless you cut it off in comments and post above), and hence `row[1]` does not exist, only `row[0]`. Try adding a where clause in sql: `WHERE time IS NOT NULL AND voltage IS NOT NULL`.